# Understanding Binary cross entropy loss

Tags: probability, distributions

[image]

This picture is taken from this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/where-did-the-binary-cross-entropy-loss-function-come-from-ac3de349a715).

Can we combine the $p$ and $1-p$ like this:

$$P(y|x) = y \times p + (1-y) \times (1-p) ;$$

it gives $p$ when $y=1$ and $(1-p)$ when $y=0.$

If so, then why don't we use this instead?

Comment: See [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution#Properties).

Comment: So does it mean that we can remove the log from the loss function?

Comment: “Why don’t we use this instead?” Instead of … what? The title asks about binary cross entropy loss, but there’s no clear connection to that loss articulated in the question. A person might guess at your meaning, but a guess might also be wrong. Can you [edit] to clarify what you know and what you want to know?

Comment: So what should I put the title then? "Why not express/calculate BCE loss this way?"

Comment: Editing both the title and the body to clearly articulate what you want to know would be a great help!